# Projectile motion question - finding launch angle given only range and initial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, projectile

this is a first year physics problem about projectile motion, which I usually am pretty good with but this question confused me because it doesn't state that the motorcycle lands on the same elevation as when it took off the ramp.

> In 1999, Robbie Knievel was the first to jump
> the Grand Canyon on a motorcycle. At a narrow
> part of the canyon (69.0 m wide) and traveling
> 35.8 m/s off the takeoff ramp, he reached the
> other side. What was his launch angle?

From this question all I know is that $d_x = 69.0m$ and $v_i = 35.8m/s$ and so, $v_{ix} = 35.8cos\theta$ $m/s$, $v_{iy} = 35.8*sin\theta$ $m/s$ and $a_y=-9.8m/s^2$ and from there I was stuck for about half an hour plugging it in all the different equations and seeing if I could work something out.

Then, I ended up looking at the answer key and found that the range equation ($R = \frac{v^2sin2\theta}{g}$)gets the answer in the answer key which is $\theta = 15.6$ degrees

My question is if this question is badly worded (therefore, impossible to solve) and I'm justified in being stuck on this problem for so long? My class didn't even teach the range formula but from what I've learned online, it should only be valid in problems that start and end at the same elevation because of the way it is derived?

I would appreciate it if there was some clarification on this, thanks!

edit: just to clarify, **I am not asking for opinions**, I am specifically asking **if this question would have been impossible to solve** **had we not assumed the launch height and landing height are the same.** The question does not explicitly state that launch height and final height are same, nor does it imply anything like that. Would that not make this question flawed? Or is there another equation or method I can use to solve this question without that assumption?

Comment: "My question is if this question is badly worded and I'm justified in being stuck on this problem for so long?" Not really a physics question, and seems to be opinion based...

Comment: Range equation is an application of the kinematic equations you learned. Yes, the one you have written is valid when the launch height and final height are the same.

Comment: Yes, since this question does not explicitly state that launch height and final height are the same, isn't this question flawed? or am i able to use another equation?

Comment: Also, to me this is a legitimate question! I am asking if this question is impossible to solve without just assuming launch height and final height are the same. It would definitely be badly worded since I felt like I was doing it the wrong way with the range equation..., this is definitely not opinion based, and I can change my wording in my question to be clearer, but I did not ask for opinions, I asked for if this question was impossible to solve and I would have been justified in just being stuck.

Comment: I think it looks better with your edit. OTOH... it's still a homework/check-my-work question that is not really going to be helpful to anyone else, so probably will (and should) still be closed.

Comment: When I posted this, I thought it was more of asking about kinematics in general, and not just for one homework problem. It would be very helpful to know for anyone to know that a question that asks for the angle given only the initial velocity and the range is impossible to solve unless the question explicitly tells u information about the launch height and final height. It touches more on the subject of what is absolutely needed and what is not. But I'm just glad to have an answer even if this question if closed so thanks!

Comment: I guess next time what I can do is just not refer to a problem but make up my own scenario where initial velocity and range is given and ask if I can find a launch angle from that, It would be the same question, but would look less like homework checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit: just to clarify, I am not asking for opinions, I am specifically asking if this question would have been impossible to solve had we not assumed the launch height and landing height are the same.

If the start and final heights are different, you can not solve it with that range equation you wrote ($ R = \frac{v_0^2}{g}\sin(2\theta)$), because that equation is derived based on the assumption that the start and final heights are the same.

So, it seems like the answer to your question is: Yes, you're right, it's not possible to solve without knowing or assuming that the start and final heights are the same.

In general, if the start height and the final height are **not** the same you can still solve it, if the **height difference** is specified, but you would use a different equation than the range equation you wrote.